# How can I read the unclaimed fees by Uniswap V3 liquidity providing through another smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, uniswap, static-call

I need to get a precise reading of the fees generated by a liquidity providing position I opened on **Uniswap V3**, and I need to get it on another smart contract (**not on a frontend**, so no use in considering APIs).

My steps have been:

1. Created a pair of custom tokens on kovan testnet
2. Created a liquidity pool using the two tokens on the official testnet Uniswap V3 (address 0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88)
3. Created a custom smart contract on which I am depositing my NFT. This smart contract must be able to access through a **read function** the unclaimed fees generated by the underlying position.

After an extensive research **it does not seem to exist an official Uniswap function to read the unclaimed fees onchain**, but by digging in their frontend code I realized that they calculate the user unclaimed fees by calling the `collect` function forcing read-only state through the `STATICCALL` opcode.

So I tried to replicate it in my smart contract in a `view` function but the `STATICCALL` call continues to fail.

Here is my relevant smart contract code:

```
[...]
IINonfungiblePositionManager NFPosManager = INonfungiblePositionManager(0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88);
[...]
function getUnclaimedFeeBalanceOfNFT(uint256 objectId) public view returns (bool _success, bytes memory data) {

     (_success, data) = address(NFPosManager).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSelector(INonfungiblePositionManager.collect.selector, INonfungiblePositionManager.CollectParams({
          tokenId: objectId,
          recipient: address(this),
          amount0Max: type(uint128).max,
          amount1Max: type(uint128).max
     })));
       
     return (_success, data);
}
```

When calling the `collect` function in this manner (before depositing the NFT on my smart contract) the `INonfungiblePositionManager` smart contract receives the transaction but returns:

```
0:
bool: _success false
1:
bytes: data 0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c4e6f7420617070726f7665640000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The `data` field, decoded from bytes, is a 'Not approved' error generated by Uniswap `NonfungiblePositionManager` smart contract.

After having deposited the NFT on my smart contract, the return values changes in:

```
0:
bool: _success false
1:
bytes: data 0x
```

So no answer ...

Here are the link of the used Uniswap smart contract repo:
https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol

Does anyone encounter the same problem?
Am I doing something wrong?
Is there another method to read the unclaimed fees **onchain**?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st part, the collect function has the modifier

```
modifier isAuthorizedForToken(uint256 tokenId) {
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(msg.sender, tokenId), 'Not approved');
}
```

with `_isApprovedOrOwner` being part of the ERC721 implementation (check [OpenZeppelin doc](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#ERC721-_isApprovedOrOwner-address-uint256-)).

So for a contract to call this function, even with a non-state changing staticcall, it needs to either be the owner or be approved.

For the 2nd part, it seems `STATICCALL` prevents modifying the state, and because `collect` tries to change state it reverts, as per [EIP-214](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-214).

Afaik there's no way to know the UNI v3 fees from inside a smart contract without collecting them. Not sure why such a design it is indeed inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I was trying to get the value of unclaimed fees within Solidity and found `tokensOwed0` and `tokensOwed1` were always coming back with `0`.

After reading the UniswapV3 Book, I found this section about updating fees: https://uniswapv3book.com/docs/milestone_5/swap-fees/#updating-position-fees-and-token-amounts. This gave me the following idea which ended up working for my use case.

Call `collect` with a value of `1 wei` for each amounts. This triggered an update and then the next call to `positions` returned the right values for `tokensOwed0` and `tokensOwed1`. Here's some example code to show you what I mean:

```
// Collect 1 wei worth of tokens so that `tokensOwed0` and `tokensOwed1` are updated
nonfungiblePositionManager.collect(
    INonfungiblePositionManager.CollectParams({
        tokenId: tokenId,
        recipient: address(this),
        amount0Max: 1,
        amount1Max: 1
    })
);

// Get the Uniswap V3 NFT
(, , state.token0, state.token1, , , , , , , state.tokensOwed0, state.tokensOwed1) = nonfungiblePositionManager.positions(tokenId);
```

Might not be the best since it actually performs a collection, but at least it gets the job done. Hopefully someone will find a better way that doesn't involve doing this tiny collection.

Note: This won't work if there's 0 fees to collect from the pool for either `token0` or `token1`. I tried to collect 0 fees but that seems to revert, which makes sense.